# Why does IDEA mark classes even with the library showing up in External Libraries?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm installing the Mail plugin for my Play application, and after adding dependencies and running `sbt dependencies` and `sbt update`, in External Libraries `play.libs.mailer.Email` does show up. However, when I import it, Intellij Marks `mailer` as red, and if I just put `play.libs.mailer.Email` in code, Intellij marks `Email` as red, but not mailer.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: if you have added dependency and its not taking effects try play clean

Comment: Can you execute **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart** in IDEA? It tends to be very stubborn to re-read build configuration at times and it should convince it to do so. Also, what's the version of IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using IDEA 13+, which has support for SBT projects (without something like gen-idea).

Things to try, sorted in severity of least to most invasive.

1. View > SBT > Refresh. This will have IDEA requery SBT for dependencies.
2. Restart IDEA.
3. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart. These caches take a while to rebuild (which is why they exist), but this has fixed plenty of problems for me.
4. Close IDEA, remove the `.idea` directory, and reopen the SBT project in IDEA.